# How to limit messages from the wall command to a specific group?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, group, wall

The description for the `wall` command states that it sends a message to *all* logged in users. However, the man page describes a flag, `-g --group`, which allows the sender to limit messages to a specified group:

> `-g, --group group` Limit printing message to members of group defined as a group argument.  The argument can be group name or GID.

However, I am only able to send messages to all logged in users. I have tried this command with:

- `-g my_group`,
- `--group my_group`,
- `-g "my_group"`,
- `--group "my_group"`,
- `--group=my_group`

In addition, I have tried all of the above by replacing "my_group" (the group name) with the group ID to no avail.

I have also tried placing the flags *after* the message. None of this works to limit the messages to a given group. All messages go to all users. Am I misunderstanding the flag? The syntax? Is this command broken? Or is the man page simply incorrect? Please do not offer alternative commands, I am aware of their existence. I want to know how to use a listed option or why the option is not working correctly. I am using `Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: Haven't tried to reproduce it, but I vaguely remember something similar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the [group membership checking code](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/v2.37.4/term-utils/wall.c#L152-L179). Had a round of `gdb --args wall -g root foobarbaz`,

```
break is_gr_member
run
{wait for breakpoint to be hit}
finish 
print utmpptr->ut_user # this prints my own user name
step # this shows we're actually taking the branch as if I was a member of group root
```

So, yeah, that's a bug in `wall`'s checking of group membership as it seems. Feel free to open a bug report on [their bug tracker](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/new); however, honestly, the pressure to fix this should be very low! I doubt there's many legitimate users of this feature. Fixing this yourself would probably be pretty valuable, still, and if you have the C skills, please do that.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because I asked, "Is the command broken?" And it appears there is a bug. Thanks!